# Import css in Django

Tags: html, django, css, django-templates

I use django1.10

i reference the official doc
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial06/

my project name:mysite

structure:

- mysite-

  ```
       - mysite - urls.py

                 -views.py

                  ...

       - templates - index.html 

                   - images 
       - static - mysite - assets - css - main.css

                                  - js

                                  ...
  ```

  In my index.html

add

`{% load staticfiles % }
        <link rel="stylesheet" text = 'html/css' href="{% static 'mysite/static/main.css' %}" />`

it said i have a Invalid block tag about TemplateSyntaxError
`<link rel="stylesheet" type = 'text/css' href="{% static 'mysite/static/assets/css/main.css' %}" />`

views.py (about static files part)
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/mysite/static/',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT='/mysite/static/'`

what's part should i notice?

Answer (score 1):

Hi dear try to make python manage.py collectstatic...
hope it solves your problem

Comment: `You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?` is this message normal? how should i choose?

Comment: yes i'm sure it will make it work if u are working on a production server or you should specify the current location of the static directory in your settings STATIC_ROOT="/mysite/static/"

Comment: Yes that message is normal. You really should do that any time you make any changes or add any other static files to your project. It's just a simple check to make you recheck everything so the django developers don't have a lot of people complaining about lost files